# Running c# project on different separated PCs?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have build simple phonebook using c# and mysql server 2005, i should run this program on two different computers ( no network ) but the data in the two versions should be the same, how could I make backup from the first version and import it to another and vice-verse to keep data consistent in the two versions on different PCs.

Comment: You can't do that unless there is any means of communication between two PCs

Comment: @Haris: perhaps that's what he's asking...

Comment: this really sounds like a database issue. And is it mysql or MS SQL 2005?

Comment: Do you allow changes of already existing records? If so, you will get trouble synchronizing the data since both users could change the same data record.

Comment: More information regarding how often you'd need to sync, and whether both instances will be updating the databases would be helpful. Are there phone lines available? Are the pc's in wireless range of eachother?

Answer (score 1):

Check the `mysqldump` utility that comes with mysql, it allows to export data to a file which can then be reimported with the `mysql` command line client. Obviously, you'll then need to transport this file on an USB stick or a CD or any other *Sneakernet Protocol*.

Answer (score 1):

At the [MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/backup-methods.html), there are several backup methods listed:

- Making Backups by Copying Table Files
- Making Delimited-Text File Backups
- Making Backups with `mysqldump` or `mysqlhotcopy`
- Making Incremental Backups by Enabling the Binary Log
- Making Backups Using Replication Slaves
- Making Backups Using a File System Snapshot

Most people use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-mysqldump.html) and you can reload the SQL file generated. I remember using `rsync` between Linux systems but since you specified C#, that is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using MS SQL2005?
You can backup your database using SSMS and then import the .bak file in the other PC. If you are using express edition you won't be able to create jobs to schedule the backups, but you can run a script as a scheduled task:

sqlcmd -S InstanceName -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [DatabaseName] TO DISK = 'C:\Backups\BackupFile.bak' WITH FORMAT"